# wsdl.exe - Specifying a type for use=literal messages is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, asmx, .net-1.1

I'm attempting to generate a service client using wsdl.exe for an external endpoint. This environment is limited to .Net 1.1. Using wsld.exe to generate the interface the following error is shown in the generated code.

// CODEGEN: The operation binding 'XXX' from namespace 'htp://example.com/xxx' was ignored.  Specifying a type for use=literal messages is not supported.

How can I get around this error using .Net 1.1?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I don't believe you can get around that. The service is not WS-I BP 1.1 compliant, and you'll be lucky to get it to _ever_ work with wsdl.exe or a web reference.

Comment: @HighCore: yes, it exists, along with Windows Server 2000.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I was being sarcastic dude.. I know it exists.. yet I'll never understand why is anyone using that in 2014...

Comment: @HighCore: for the same reason there are still people using Windows Server 2000 and 2003 and Windows XP.

Comment: I'll have to admit, I almost put something like "OK, don't laugh at me" when I put down .Net 1.1. Yes it's an antiquated technology. Unfortunately I'm having to modify a legacy system. Hey, it pays the bills! :) Thanks for the comments! Cobol anyone?